# Vee Validate property or method "errors" is not defined Nuxt JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm trying to install Vee Validate into my Nuxt JS v2.6.3 application. I'm using Nuxt JS in universal mode, and have added a `vee-validate.js` plugin file in the plugins folder, the contents of this file are:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';

Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false });
```

I have then included this in my `nuxt.config.js` file using the `server` mode for this file:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  { mode: 'server', src: '@/plugins/vee-validate' }
  ...
]
```

Then, in my **page**, but I have also tried a component file as well, I've got a simple input setup with validation:

**pages/apply.vue**

```html
<div class="form-group mb-0" v-if="loaded">
  <label class="form-label" for="AppLoanPurposeOther">Please tell us the reason for your loan:</label>
  <input v-validate="'required'" v-bind:class="errors.has('data[ApplicationPayday][AppLoanPurposeOther]') ? 'is-invalid' : ''" name="data[ApplicationPayday][AppLoanPurposeOther]" id="AppLoanPurposeOther" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text">
</div>
```

Unfortunately, with this setup I get the following console error:

`Property or method "errors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

This is rather frustrating, as it is included in the project, I have Vee Validate version 2.2.7, and have tried switching the mode of the Vee Validate JS file, I've tried using: `inject: true` and `inject: false`, with little luck.

What am I missing?